# The abbreviation impl is used in a lot of libraries; What does it mean?

Tags: naming-conventions, libraries

I've seen impl used as namespaces and as a class suffix in a number of different .net and Java libraries.  I just want to know what it means and why it is used.

Comment: So do they use a 'BaseClass' suffix in Java?  I see it sometimes in .net code.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It stands for **Implementation**.

It's a Java convention.

Often in java (particularly J2EE) you will get an object from some factory, and then use it.

That object's type is often given to you as an interface, so that you don't need to know the actual class, just its methods.

An *impl* class is usually a class that implements the behaviour described by one of these interfaces.

Comment: [ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library) also likes to uses `Impl` as a suffix in COM class implementation modules (to differentiate them from the library's entry point module).

Comment: this is a really horrible [naming convention anti-pattern](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/02/interface-and-class-naming-anti-patterns-java-naming-convention-tautologies/)

Comment: @feelingunwelcome I don't disagree - the main thing here is that if you want to test easily in java/j2ee you often end up with a 1:1 class/interface ratio to break apart your dependencies.  Naming can start to be a real pain in those circumstances.  It *does* avoid the "IInterfaceName" issue - it just moves the ugly to a different place.

Comment: To me the `Impl` convention is an indicator that the class is intended to be instantiated through something like a factory rather than directly via its constructor. Though if that's the intent there are better ways to accomplish that.

Comment: Impl is also an indicator that there's only one damn implementation, and from what I've seen it's more verbose pattern/YAGNI garbage infecting the Java world. Delete the interface - they aren't that hard to add if you find that you need it later anyway!

Answer (score 18):

It's short for "implementation".  Generally it's used when the parent package contains abstract classes, interfaces, and perhaps some factory classes which are the main point of access, and then the `impl` package contains various concrete implementations of those abstract classes and interfaces.